# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() when create registration form

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to create application for registration. But i have an error. java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
whats wrong? this is my full class

```
public class signup_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username_reg;
    EditText email_reg;
    EditText password_reg;
    Button signup_reg;

    String url_server = "http://192.168.1.215/register.php";

    TextView tanggal_reg;
    Boolean cekinput;
    String aksi;
    String tanggal_kirim;
    HttpResponse response;
    String GetUsername, GetEmail, GetPassword, GetTanggal;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        username_reg = (EditText)findViewById(usernameup);
        email_reg = (EditText)findViewById(emailup);
        password_reg = (EditText)findViewById(passwordup);
        signup_reg = (Button)findViewById(signup);
        tanggal_reg = (TextView)findViewById(tanggalup);


        signup_reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Getcekinputkosong();
                if(cekinput){
                    kirimdata(GetUsername, GetEmail, GetPassword, GetTanggal);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(signup_activity.this, "Data yang anda isikan belum lengkap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG). show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Getcekinputkosong(){
        GetUsername = username_reg.getText().toString();
        GetEmail = email_reg.getText().toString();
        GetPassword = password_reg.getText().toString();
        GetTanggal=tanggal_reg.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(GetUsername) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetEmail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetPassword) || TextUtils.isEmpty(GetTanggal)) {
            cekinput = false;
        }
        else {
            cekinput = true;
        }
    }
    public void kirimdata(final String username_reg, final String email_reg, final String password_reg, final String tanggal_reg) {
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String username_kirim = username_reg;
                String email_kirim = email_reg;
                String password_kirim = password_reg;
                String tanggal_kirim = tanggal_reg;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_reg", username_kirim));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_reg", email_kirim));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_reg", password_kirim));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal_reg", tanggal_kirim));
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_server);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return "Data Berhasil Terkirim";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Toast.makeText(signup_activity.this, "Data Berhasil Terkirim", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(username_reg, email_reg, password_reg);
    }

    public void kembali_login(View arg0){
        Intent kembali = new Intent(signup_activity.this, register_activity.class);
        startActivity(kembali);
        signup_activity.this.finish();
    }


    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new datepickerlah();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

}
```

I am getting this Error while running:

> E/AndroidRuntime:
>       FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>       Process: com.example.client18.dd, PID: 8356
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>       doInBackground()
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>
> ```
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)     
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)                                                                            
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)                                                                           
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException                                        
>
> at com.example.client18.dd.signup_activity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(signup_activity.java:128)
>
> at com.example.client18.dd.signup_activity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(signup_activity.java:112)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)                                                                           
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)                                                                            
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)                                                                             
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
> ```

Comment: post full error, and which library your are using for Http?

Comment: @sasikumar of course

Comment: String username_kirim = username_reg;
                String email_kirim = email_reg;
                String password_kirim = password_reg;
                String tanggal_kirim = tanggal_reg;

where are your those strings?

Comment: @DennyKurniawan Post your full Activity class

Comment: @DennyKurniawan you are getting .NullPointerException at signup_activity.java:128

Comment: which line is 128 in your signup_activity?

Comment: ok, that my full class.

Comment: line 128 is nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_reg", password_kirim)); @Na

Comment: You are initialing views in a wrong way , it should be `username_reg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameup);` , do this for all edit text views and what is this `(EditText)findViewById(usernameup)`

Comment: Make Sure that Your URL is working!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my register.php

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database = "contohdatabase";
$koneksi = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);
 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$nama = $_POST['username_reg'];
$email = $_POST['email_reg'];
$password = $_POST['password_reg'];
$tanggal_lahir = $_POST['tanggal_reg'];
$tambahdata = "INSERT INTO login(username, email, password, tanggal_lahir) VALUE($nama, $email, $password, $tanggal_lahir);";
if(mysql_query($koneksi,$tambahdata)){
echo "Data berhasil diinput ";
}
else {
echo "Data tidak sukses terkirim";
}
echo "$result";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here,

```
 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

You have not initialize "response" and use it.so, replace it with "httpResponse".